# Magic manga with two brothers, one of them wears glasses

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

It's been long so I can't remember the name anymore. The manga has no colour, it's black and white. I just remember one scene. The younger brother (I guess) has strength and is always protecting the older brother with glasses. And the scene I remember is that at (magic) school, on a field training, the one with glasses uses black magic and controls it very well, and is called a genius. Of the brothers, one has black hair and glasses (kind of a bookworm) and the other is playful with spiky hair (always protecting his brother).

Well, that's all I can remember. Does anyone know the title of the manga? I really can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Blue Exorcist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Exorcist).

The description of two brothers (one looking like a bookworm (Yukio) and the other (Rin) being a complete opposite) matches.

[image] [image]